# Hide sensitive string in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a WebGL game that requires users to enter their phone number to play the game. It will send a request to an API that will check if the phone number exists in the database or not. The problem I have now is I'm hardcoding my API token on the file, something like this:

```
public string token = "p2lbgWkFrykA4QyUmpHihzmc5BNzIABq";
```

I know it's bad practice and people can easily see this but is there a way to hide this or encrypt it so it's not easily visible? I'm not saying to make it secure because obviously if the token is in the file, it can be grabed,  but just to make it a little bit harder for people to see the token.

Comment: No sane person would look into code to get the secret that used for HTTP communication when you can just grab that from the HTTP/HTTPS traffic directly... Not really sure what you want to protect from - depending on your actual goals some guidance may be provided... Also consider reading related information on [security.se]...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov not sure what u mean by grab from traffic means? The api is secured by the token, so if they want to make a request to that api they would have to get the token first. The token is what im trying to protect.

Comment: Every api needs a public token, it would be hard to prevent that from being exposed. If you need to protect this token move the functionality to a secure api where this token can be used. Then your own api could have a public token that doesn't have to be protected

Comment: @stalwart1014 Do you have control of the code for the API that you are hitting, or is it a 3rd party service?